# Using KCron in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, cron

I tried to install KCron in Kubuntu 15.04. I could find the package in Muon but after installing it I can't find it in the application menu. Also I can't start it by running "kcron" in the console.

I read KCron is included in kdeadmin package but I can not find that package using apt-get or Muon.

So how can I use KCron? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, using Kubuntu 15.04 KCron must be started using the command line:

```
kdesudo kcmshell4 kcm_cron
```

The corresponding package is kde-config-cron.

Using 15.10 it seems there is an entry in the system settings but I couldn't test this yet.